# get the execution location from within a library jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a class named `Utils` with a static method that should determine the execution location.

```
public class Utils {
   public static Path getExecutionLocation() throws URISyntaxException {
     return Paths.get(Utils.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
   }
}
```

Within eclipse this gives me: `C:\Users\USERNAME\workspace\PROJECT\bin\main\`

Run as a jar this gives me: `C:\PATH\TO\JAR\thatJar.jar`

Both is correct and expected.

Now I have that `Utils` class inside a library called `someLib.jar`.
When I use that library in another project it works if I build a jar of that project with `someLib.jar` inside.
But in eclipse it returns the path to `someLib.jar`.

I want it to return the path to the execution directory of the project:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\workspace\A_PROJECT_USING_SOMELIB\bin\main\`

I tried

`return new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()).toPath();`

But that failed inside a jar because `getResource(".")` results in `null`.

I could give `getExecutionLocation` a class from inside the project as a parameter and excute `getProtectionDomain()` on that. But I want to ask here if someone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution based on `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` approach that gives me the class loader responsible for the main entry point of the project that is using someLib.jar.

Within an IDE I can use `getResource(".")` to get URL of the root path of all resources (and sources).

From jar file this does not work. So I use `getResource("META-INF")` to get URL of the META-INF folder (that has the manifest inside) and should always exist in jar files.

Maybe still not optimal. But so far I can work with it.

```
public static Path getExecutionLocation() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    // System ClassLoader is on the highest level and responsible for the main entry point
    ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    // get the resources root path (works within IDEs)
    URL executionLocation = systemClassLoader.getResource(".");
    // fallback for jars
    if(executionLocation == null) {
        // look for META-INF folder
        URL metaInfLocation = systemClassLoader.getResource("META-INF");
        // URL looks like "jar:file:/C:/path/to/jar/jarfile.jar!/META-INF"
        // openConnection on URL - does not really establish connection but checks if URL would be valid
        JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) metaInfLocation.openConnection();
        // extracts URL to jar file
        executionLocation = connection.getJarFileURL();
    }
    // impossible to determine
    if(executionLocation == null) throw new RuntimeException("Impossible to determine exeution location");
    
    return Paths.get(executionLocation.toURI());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public class Utils {
   public static Path getExecutionLocation(Class c) throws URISyntaxException {
        return Paths.get(c.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    }
}
```

So you pass the class as an argument to the function. For example:

```java
public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Utils.getExecutionLocation(Main.class);
        }
    }
```

Note that there may be more straightforward solutions,
But this is the first one that came into my mind, and I thought, why not :)

Comment: I should've read your question 'till the end. You even pointed this solution out, and I payed no attention to it. Sorry, leaving this answer as it may help somebody else.